# Wait for multiple promises to be rejected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Doing some testing, I need to wait for a couple of promises to be rejected.

I know that I can use jQuery.when() to wait for several promises tu be resolved. But that method reject the master promise as soon one of the promises fails.

I know that all my promises will fail, but I need to wait for it anyway. How can I do it?

In a kind of pseudo-code what I want to do is:

```
var promise1 = connection.doCall();
var promise2 = connection.doCall();

$.when([promise1, promise2]).allOfThemFail(function() {
    assertThatSomeProcessWasDoneOnlyOnce()
});
```

Comment: `$.when` does not take an array?

Comment: What if one of your promises *didn't* fail; would you want the promise chain to take the success path or the error path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Bluebird promise library, you can use `Promise.settle()` which waits for all the promises to be settled (e.g. fulfilled or rejected) and then you can simply query the list to see if they were all rejected.

```
var p1 = connection.doCall();
var p2 = connection.doCall();
Promise.settle([p1, p2]).then(function(results) {
    var allRejected = results.every(function(item) {
        return item.isRejected();
    });
    // act on allRejected here
});
```

---

Here's a jQuery-specific version of `settle()`:

```
(function() {    

    function isPromise(p) {
        return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
    }

    function wrapInPromise(p) {
        if (!isPromise(p)) {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    // pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
    $.settle = function(p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        }

        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            // make sure p is a promise (it could be just a value)
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            // Now we know for sure that p is a promise
            // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
            return p.then(function(val) {
                return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
            }, function(reason) {
                // convert rejected promise into resolved promise by returning a resolved promised
                // One could just return the promiseInspection object directly if jQuery was
                // Promise spec compliant, but jQuery 1.x and 2.x are not so we have to take this extra step
                return wrapInPromise(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
            });
        })).then(function() {
              // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
              // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    }

})();
```

And, you would use this similarly to the Bluebird solution:

```
var p1 = connection.doCall();
var p2 = connection.doCall();
$.settle([p1, p2]).then(function(results) {
    var allRejected = results.every(function(item) {
        return item.isRejected();
    });
    // act on allRejected here
});
```

---

And, here's a `settle()` type function build from scratch using standard ES6 promises.  It returns a single promise that is resolved when all the other promises have finished (regardless of their final state).  The resolved result of this uber promise is an array of `PromiseInspection` objects where you can query `isFulfilled()` or `isRejected()` and can obtain the `.value()` or `.reason()`.

```
Promise.isPromise = function(p) {
    return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
}

// ES6 version of settle
Promise.settle = function(promises) {
    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    return Promise.all(promises.map(function(p) {
        // make sure any values are wrapped in a promise
        if (!Promise.isPromise(p)) {
            p = Promise.resolve(p);
        }
        return p.then(function(val) {
            return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
        }, function(err) {
            return new PromiseInspection(false, val);
        });
    }));
}
```

And, you would use this similarly as above:

```
var p1 = connection.doCall();
var p2 = connection.doCall();
Promise.settle([p1, p2]).then(function(results) {
    var allRejected = results.every(function(item) {
        return item.isRejected();
    });
    // act on allRejected here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Bluebird, that's a excelent Library.
And +1 for Settle implementation using ES6 Promises !

@aron-p-johny answer is  worth noting because it is implemented using jQuery promises and do not depends on other libraries, nor almost bleeding edge (in mid-2015)  features.

Comment: Made a couple edits to handle the case of a zero length promise array or the case of non-promises (e.g. just values) passed in the array.

Comment: Added jQuery-specific version of `$.settle()`.

Comment: Updated standard Promise implementation to work identically to the other two implementations and to use `Promise.all()` internally to get its job done rather than writing our own promise tracking logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in function for that, but you can easily implement

```
var promise1 = connection.doCall();
var promise2 = connection.doCall();

allOfThemFail([promise1, promise2]).always(function () {
    assertThatSomeProcessWasDoneOnlyOnce()
});


function allOfThemFail(array) {
    var count = 0;
    len = array.length, failed = false, deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.each(array, function (i, item) {
        item.fail(fail).always(always);
    })


    function always() {
        if (++count == len) {
            if (failed) {
                deferred.reject();
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }
    }

    function fail() {
        failed = true;
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```