# Implementing a mix of Promise.all and Promise.settle

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I need to implement a version of `Promise.all` that would take an array of promises and return the result as it usually does, plus also settles all promises, much like `Promise.settle` does it within the `Bluebird` library, except I cannot use `Bluebird`, and have to rely just on the standard promise protocol.

Would that be terribly complicated to implement? Or is it too much to ask here for an idea of how to implement it? I really hope not, so I'm asking, if anyone perhaps implemented it before, to share the idea of how to do it right.

The premise for this is to be able to use it within a database transaction that needs to do `commit`/`rollback` once the call has finished, and it cannot have loose promises still trying to resolve outside the transaction call.

**EDIT:** The link provided to another question is very useful, but it is not a complete answer to the question that was asked. A generic `settle` is a great example that helped a lot, but it needed to be simplified and wrapped into `all` logic to fit the transactions scenario described earlier.

Comment: Code provided for exactly what you're asking for here (in the second code example named `promiseSettle()`): [Wait for multiple promises to be rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241391/wait-for-multiple-promises-to-be-rejected).   Marked this question as a dup of that one.

Comment: It was a very useful reference, although offering only half the answer.

Comment: What half is missing.  It runs all promises and tells you when they are all done.

Comment: It creates a needless array of objects with fulfilled statuses, and it doesn't implement the merging logic like the one I wrote based on the example.

Comment: A simplification, more like, because some things in the generic implementation are not needed when it is done strictly in the context of `all` as the containing operation.

Comment: It's a specialization of a generic capability that loses the ability to do any other flavors of `.settle()`.  From a software design capability, I'd prefer to keep the generic function and then wrap it to offer the specialized result.  That provides a lot more flexibility in the future at the cost of only a few more lines of code.

Comment: Unmarked as a dup because the OP wasn't actually asking for `.settle()`, but some specialized derivation of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the generic `promiseSettle()` function from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241391/wait-for-multiple-promises-to-be-rejected), you could do this and have both a generic `settle()` type function and your much more specific version as a wrapper around it.  This would give you the generic ability to do lots of `.settle()` types of behavior and have your own specific flavor and also build other specific flavors as needed:

So, here's the generic `promiseSettle()` that returns you the state of all the promises and resolves only when all the passed-in promises are done:

```
function promiseSettle(promises) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var remaining = promises.length;
        // place to store results in original order
        var results = new Array(remaining);

        function checkDone() {
            if (--remaining === 0) {
                resolve(results);
            }
        }

        promises.forEach(function(item, index) {
            // check if the array entry is actually a thenable
            if (typeof item.then === "function") {
                item.then(function(value) {
                    // success
                    results[index] = {state: "fulfilled", value: value};
                    checkDone();
                }, function(err) {
                    // reject error
                    results[index] = {state: "rejected", value: err};
                    checkDone();
                });
            } else {
                // not a thenable, just return the item itself
                results[index] = {state: "fulfilled", value: item}
                --remaining;
            }
        });
        // special case for zero promises passed
        if (remaining === 0) {
            resolve(results);
        }
    });
}
```

And, here's a wrapper on it that gives you your specific behavior:

```
// Either fulfills with an array of results or
// rejects with the first error, but it does not do either
// until all promises have completed which makes it different than
// promise.all()
function promiseSettleAll(promises) {
    return promiseSettle(promises).then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].state !== "fulfilled") {
                // reject with the first error found
                throw results[i].value;
            }
        }
        // all were successful, return just array of values
        return results.map(function(item) {return item.value;});
    });
}
```

Comment: Simplified `promiseSettleAll()` by using a plain `for` loop.

Comment: After a careful consideration, I decided to track all rejects also. It does seem like a good idea after all :)

Comment: @vitaly-t - Interesting.  What led to the change of mind?

Comment: Use of the same method outside of transactions, in tasks. A database task is like a transaction, just without `begin/commit/rollback` parts, and in those cases one is likely to want details on every reject, since a failed task doesn't result in a `rollback`. I wasn't considering this case initially.

Comment: I've first updated my example, but it got too much specifics in it now, so then I marked it for deletion, to avoid confusion, and accepted your answer, even though my final version was a bit different. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think the solution by jfriend is overly complex because it builds on top of `settle`, it runs a semaphore and does a lot of weird stuff instead of using the built in primitives like `.all`.

Instead, if we build on Bluebird's newer `reflect` primitive (implementing it in native promises) we can get a much cleaner API and implementation:

```
function reflect(promise){
    return promise.then(x => ({state: "fulfilled", value: x}), // arrows, assume nodejs
                        e => ({state: "rejected" , value: e}));
}
```

On top of reflect, we can build the other primitives easily:

```
function settle(promises){
    return Promise.all(promises.map(reflect)); // much cleaner
}
```

If we want to wait and then resolve/reject based on values it's simply:

```
function allWait(promises){
    return settle(promises).then(results => {
       var firstFailed = results.find(r => r.state === "rejected");
       if(firstFailed) throw firstFailed.value;
       return results; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather reject with an array here?

Comment: @Bergi I wanted to show the correct way to write the same code. Personally I would not handle transactions like this to begin with - I'd use disposers and the disposer pattern, like ORMs do.

Comment: The question clearly states, and it is mentioned in comments in several places, that I needed a solution based on the standard promises, not one specific promise library. I cannot use Bluebird's `settle` or anything something like this. jfriend00's solution is the one that works for me.

Comment: @vitaly-t this answer does not use bluebird promises or any promise library, everything here is standard. I have read your question.

Comment: @vitaly-t I don't see bluebird (or anything bluebird specific) in his answer. Also, the solution here is shorter, more expressive and much more readable than the accepted answer.

Comment: What does "=>" even mean? I'm not sure how to read such code.

Comment: @vitaly-t open your developer tools (F12) go to the console and test it out, it's an ES2015 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :) It's definitely JavaScirpt and it works in modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge) today, more importantly - since your code is node then you can use it in your code no issues. If you don't want to use it - you can just change `x => y` to `function(x){ return y; }` in this case.

Comment: Right, I'm using the very latest version of Node JS 0.12.7, and it doesn't recognize it. Also, in the code that I was using eventually I am resolving with an array of resolved results, and only for the reject i'm returning array of {success, result}. This makes it compatible with results from `promise.all`, and much easier to use ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t that's not the latest version of Node by a long shot https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/ but if you feel like not using it - then you're welcome to use `function(x){ return y; }`. Arrow functions are a native ES2015 feature (very much like promises) - so I assumed since the topic is an ES2015 feature that's supported in modern environments (promises) then these features are acceptable to use here. Node 4.0 also has the advantage of having the unhandledRejection hooks so it can detect exceptions native promises swallowed - so it's well worth your upgrade.

Comment: My question was initially around an implementation to be used inside transactions, for databases, so client-side is of no interest ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t awesome, then you can use arrow functions safely :) A lot of times when you target client side you'd have to use tools that [turn new JavaScript to old JavaScript](http://babeljs.io/) for engines like internet explorer. Since you're using Node then you can use modern JavaScript (classes, generators, arrow functions, let/const) out of the box. Anyway, this answer was more about correct (native) promise usage than anything else.

Comment: I have updated my own solution - just to show what I was using in the end. And thank you for your input also, this gives some nice ideas as well. It's just that I did a few extra things on top of it, as I described in my code ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end of all the research, writing, testing and optimizations, it was turned into a library ([spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex)) that focuses on this type of things.

Specifically, method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) is the one that implements the fusion of the logic described.

I am not republishing [its source code](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/lib/ext/batch.js) here, because it now does [a lot more](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) than what was originally sought within the question.

Comment: What is the goal of this code because it is not clear what you're trying to do here and apparently I did not understand what you were trying to do in your question either.  In my code, you could just run `promiseSettle()` and then enumerate the returned results to see what succeeded and what failed.  That is, after all, what Bluebird's `.settle()` does which is what I thought you asked for.

Comment: First is to settle all the promises in the array, while doing it in such a way that's necessary in the context of the `all` operation that contains it, and then return the result with the same logic as `all` does.

Comment: But, what do you do when a promise rejects.  How do you communicate that back.  You can't return results the same way `Promise.all()` does because you have to communicate back which ones succeeded and which ones failed.

Comment: The code above does exactly all that. It's not that much different from the implementation suggested earlier, just simplified. P.S. You do not need to communicate which ones failed, only the first one that failed, according to `all` logic.

Comment: So, you only return two states: 1) all succeeded with results in an array or 2) something failed and here's the first error that occured.  Is that right?  So, if anything fails, you have access to no results and no idea which request failed?

Comment: That is correct. That's exactly what I was looking for, as per my original question, because this is the kind of logic a database transaction needs when executing an array of promise-queries, to figure out whether it should do a `rollback` or `commit`. And again yes, I don't care about results, should any promise reject, I just need the first failure details, and that's it.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer that is a wrapper on the generic `.settle()` that achieves your specific desires.  This, obviously gives you access to the generic `.settle()` capabilities and the ability to build other specialized wrappers too.  Apparently this isn't your first choice for implementation, but it is how I would do it to preserve access to the generic capability and other derived behaviors.  There is little loss of anything by having a few more lines of code and much flexibility retained by having the generic version that can actually return all results even when something rejects.